# Victory chart container interactions don't work if not pressed from data/axes

Tags: react-native, victory-charts

I'm trying to make a chart such that anywhere you hover on it (pressing for touch screen) a cursor appears (in my case a vertical line). This functionality is already present in the VictoryCursorContainer component, as can be seen on the first example in the documentation: https://formidable.com/open-source/victory/docs/victory-cursor-container.

The issue for me is that when I use the same code and run it on my IOS phone, the cursor only appears if I touch specific sections of the chart, particularly near the data points and axes of the chart. For example, if I press the part of the chart underneath the data points, nothing happens. If I start pressing on the data points/axis and then drag into that area, the cursor moves there as intended. The same phenomena occurs for the VictoryVoronoiContainer component; only some parts of the chart can be hovered.

This is *not* the case in the demo in the documentation: there, the whole chart can be hovered, which leads me to think this is a native-only issue. Does anyone know of a fix for this issue?

Comment: How did you get past this?

Comment: @SuleimanAbdulMajeed I ended up moving the project to non-Native react and used a different library that was a better fit for my needs. I don't recall finding a solution to this problem.